# Guide/Book recommendation for Kernel Newbies?

Tags: linux, shell-script, linux-kernel, c

A book which will help non-real world c/c++ programmers, to step in kernel development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding the Linux Kernel 3rd ed and Linux Device Drivers 3rd ed are two choices. They are a bit old already, but there doesn't seem to be many fresh books on this topic out there.